# Regex in PDO PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, regex, pdo

How do I use RegEx in a PDO MySQL query?

I have tried this query but it didn't work.

```
$stmtg = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE ename LIKE :e_name");
$stmtg->bindValue(":e_name", "%[$ename]%");
```

Answer (score 1):

To use regular expressions you should use `REGEXP` instead of `LIKE`:

```
$stmtg = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE ename REGEXP ':e_name'");
$stmtg->bindValue(":e_name", $ename);
```